# Find the first index for which an array goes below a certain threshold (and stay below for some time)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, threshold, windowing

Let `A` be a 1D numpy array, a threshold `t`, and a window length `K`.

**How to find the minimal index `j`, such that `A[j:j+K] < t`?** (i.e. the first time A stays below the threshold *on a full window of width K*).

I've tried (unfinished) things with a loop, but it seemed far from optimal, and I thought maybe there's a clever "numpy way" to do it.

---

Sidenote: the fact we want to test if we're below the threshold *during a certain window length* instead of ponctual value, is useful to avoid on/off/on/off/on/off artefacts near the threshold (see also [Hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis#Electronic_circuits): *"hysteresis is intentionally added to an electronic circuit to prevent unwanted rapid switching [...] compensate for contact bounce in switches, or noise in an electrical signal."*).

Comment: `next(j for j in range(len(A)-K) if all(A[j:j+K] < t), None))`?

Comment: @pault Yes, this might be it! But if the array is long, i suspect that evaluating `all(A[j:j+K] < t)` for all `j in range(len(A)-K)` might be long to compute

Comment: Divakar's solution is much faster, but `all` will short circuit and you wouldn't be checking all `j` since we're using `next`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We can use `1D convolution` -

```
np.flatnonzero(np.convolve(A<t, np.ones(K,dtype=int))==K)[0]-K+1
```

The idea is to get the boolean array after comparison against threshold and then run a `1D` convolution with a kernel of length same as `window`, filled with `1s`. This gives us sum of each sliding window. So, all windows that have sum of `K` are the ones we are after. Use `flatnonzero` to get the starting indices for the valid windows. Finally, select the first one.

**Approach #2**

With `binary-erosion` -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_erosion

np.flatnonzero(binary_erosion(A<t, np.ones(K), origin=-(K//2)))[0]
```

This runs a sliding kernel with a length same as `window` and erodes away all windows that don't have `window` length `True` ones in sequence, leaving us with the valid ones. Again, use `flatnonzero` to get the indices and finally select the first one. We need to use the arg `origin` with the binary-erosion, so that we select the starts.

**Approach #3**

Here's another with island finding -

```
# Get mask of valid elements with comparison against thresh
mask = np.r_[False,A<t,False]

# Get indices of starts and ends for the valid islands
idx = np.flatnonzero(mask[:-1] != mask[1:])
start,stop = idx[::2],idx[1::2]

# Get the island lengths and check for lengths >=K and mask  start indices
# and select the first one among them
out = start[(stop - start)>=K][0]
```

Comment: Why do you check for `>=K` instead of `==K`? The convolution terms should never exceed `K` for a kernel of ones and an array of zeros and ones (or False and True), right? I know it's just a nitpick.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa Good point! Though it won't change the performance (I would think). Edited.

Comment: @Basj, separate all the function calls and try them one after another on a simple example (like `A` with `A.size=12` and `K=3`). Then you should be able to determine what all the parts do.

Comment: @Basj Added some explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Divakar for this very interesting answer. For now, I'll use approach #2, which is the one I've understood the fastest!

Comment: @Divakar a little thing: in approach #2, [Python crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar7m4.jpg) when `K` is odd, for example with `K=3`. Is there an `origin`  parameter that would work for both odd and even `K`?

Comment: @Basj Sorry that was a bug. Fixed.

Comment: @Divakar oh right, I didn't notice the difference between `-x//2` and `-(x//2)` before... Good to know! Thanks!

Comment: As a conclusion @Divakar (I know comments are not made for discussion), in an engineering situation where you need to find the timing for which a signal goes below a threshold, would you use such techniques described here, with such a window (to ensure that it's not a 'very short outlier' that goes below the thresh but that the signal *really* significantly goes below the thresh), or would you use other techniques? Is there a name for these techniques? Would the one here be called "windowed thresholding" (never heard this) or another name maybe?